# PHP high cpu load causing error 500 however script continues to run

Tags: php

I have a php script which generates a list of tokens in the form of 20 character random strings.

Each token is created as a new row in a mysql table.

Everything runs happily, within execution time and memory parameters however when the script is executed in a browser it displays an error 500 message when the cpu load hits about 1.5 (per core)

Weirdly, the script continues to run to execution. Generating up to 1 million+ tokens... so why does the error 500 code get sent to the browser?

Comment: Check your console to see why your server has an internal server error. Alternatively, use `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in the start of your script.

Comment: also check your server log. if the timeout value is too small, you can increase it in your server config

Comment: provide your code http://pastebin.com

Comment: force the timout as mentioned, or better yet post the code so we can figure out why it is running rampant

Comment: An error 500 is related to the web server not being able to handle the request normally due in invalid configuration for the request. I would therefore be wize to look at the web server logs for error messages. Your application may be oblivious to what the 500 error is.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. :)